# Draw single Contour in OpenCV on image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, contour

What is the best way to draw a single contour in OpenCV? As far as i can see [drawContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=drawcontours#void%20drawContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20int%20contourIdx,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20InputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20maxLevel,%20Point%20offset%29) can only handle multiple contours.

Background: I want to change my code to a for each loop. The old code:

```
//vector<vector<Point> > contours = result of findContours(...)
for (int i = 0; i < contour.size; i++){
    if(iscorrect(contours[i])){
        drawContours(img, contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy);
    }
 }
```

The way presented [in this mailing list](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/draw-only-one-contour-using-drawContours-td7404400.html) is pretty ugly:

```
for (vector<Point> contour : contours){
     if(iscorrect(contour)){
          vector<vector<Point> > con = vector<vector<Point> >(1, contour);
          drawContours(img, con, -1, color, 1, 8);
     }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to draw single contours (vector< Point> Object)?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same question, and the better way that I've found until now, is this:

```
for (vector<Point> contour : contours){
  if(iscorrect(contour)){
    drawContours(img, vector<vector<Point> >(1,contour), -1, color, 1, 8);
  }
}
```

This is almost the same that you have, but one line less.

My first thought was to use `Mat(contour)` but it didn't work.

If you've found a better way to do it, publish it here and share the wisdom.

Comment: With Optimization turned on it should be identical machine code after compilation. I have no better way, maybe with openCV update there will be implemented something.

Answer (score 8):

With OpenCV 3.0 polylines() is more flexible, and we can do, e.g.:

```
vector<Point> approx;
polylines(frame, approx, true, color, 1, 8);
```

In your loop this would be:

```
for (vector<Point> contour : contours) {
    if (iscorrect(contour)) {
        polylines(frame, approx, true, color, 1, 8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using draw contours, it is not exactly pretty, but you don't need a loop.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> contour;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contourVec;
contourVec.push_back(contour);

cv::drawContours(img,contourVec,0,color,1,8,hierarchy); //Replace i with 0 for index.
```

Comment: I only want to draw contours, that fulfill certain properties. That is the reason for the iteration.